# eMac G4 does not show any OS install disks

Tags: macos, mac, emacs, powerpc

I have a eMac G4 1.0 GHz that will not see any Mac OS install disks I put in it. I am not sure if I'm making the disks wrong, or if there's something wrong with my computer. I did replace the factory cd only disk drive with a dvd drive from an old HP workstation. The only disk that will show up when you hold option is the disk for my old 2007 MacBook Pro, but since that is an intel Mac, it kernel panics. Also I can install Linux, but am afraid to do that because I don't know if I will be able to get Mac OS back. This computer is confusing me because the sticker that shows the configuration does not match any computer in the Mactracker app. I originally wanted to find out if this computer is Mac OS 9 compatible but I can't get any install disk to boot. I have tried almost everything, I've held c, I've even gone into open firmware, with still no luck. I would just like to know if this is an issue that happens or if my computer is broken. As a side note, I made discs for this computer on many computer including different macs, a windows computer, and this thing itself!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I doubt that drive from the HP will work. You may need to buy an old drive from Macsales or eBay. The maximum OS it will support is Mac OS X 10.5.8 "Leopard" and Mac OS 9.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule the install CD or DVD supplied with one model will not work with another one.

A normal purchased DVD will work on a large range of Macs.

Do you have access to a non-Intel Mac of about the same age which you can link via Firewire? If so you can use 'Target Disk Mode' to examine it or install an OS.

You will not be able to use OS 9 unless the hard disk had OS 9 drivers installed when it was formatted.

Where are you? Others in your area may have old kit which will assist you.

How did you use this computer to make a 'disk' if it won't boot?

Comment: I used it to make a disc by booting into Mac OS X. It's the HDD I got from a different eMac. On the original HDD, I formatted it and installed linux but i never saw the original copy of Mac OS again. (I apologize for not replying to these answers, sorry!) EDIT: Also I don't have any other functional non-Intel Macs, I got rid of the other eMac.